# Python How to save speech recognition word into the list?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import logging


def speechfrommicrophone():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    res=[]
    with mic as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source)
##        except sr.UnknownValueError:
##            print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
##        except sr.RequestError as e:
##            print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
    try:
        res=r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
        #print(type(res))
        print('You said:',res)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Does not received any voice there")

for i in range(10):
    print('Please say something...')  
    speechfrommicrophone()
    print('End.')
```

How can I save every time speech recognition into one list.
For example, if I said "Hello" I would like to save that hello into one list res[i]
if I want to list what I said before I can just print res.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import logging

res = []


def speechfrommicrophone():
    global res
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    with mic as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source)
##        except sr.UnknownValueError:
##            print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
##        except sr.RequestError as e:
##            print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
    try:
        a=r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
        #print(type(res))
        print('You said:',a)
        res.append(a)

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Does not received any voice there")

for i in range(10):
    print('Please say something...')
    speechfrommicrophone()
    print('End.')
    print("you said:",res)
```

try this code.It save your 10 voice in res=[] list

```
output:
Please say something...
You said: hello
End.
you said: ['hello']
Please say something...
You said: world
End.
you said: ['hello', 'world']
Please say something...
```